# Curry lodash api method

Tags: javascript, lodash

Can't understand why next code always returns function:

```
const tmp = _.curry(_.get);

console.log(tmp(someObject)('randomKeyFromObject'));
```

version: 4.17.11

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`_.get` takes three arguments (see `console.log(_.get.length)`), therefore you also have to pass three arguments to the curried version:

```
 console.log(tmp(someObject)('randomKeyFromObject')());
```

Or you use the second optional arity parameter:

```
_.curry(_.get, 2)
```

Comment: const _ = require('lodash');

const a = {
  aa: '1',
  bb: '1',
};

const tmp = _.curry(_.get);

console.log(tmp(a)('aa')());

returns function

Comment: @i47232898 I'm currently afk, could you be so nice to add a running stack snippet to your question (the `<>` button, you can also add lodash)